# How to resolve FXCop Error - CA3056

Tags: fxcop

I have following code:

```
var configuration = new XmlDocument();

configuration.Load(filePath);
```

Fxcope giving following error:

> Using this overload of System.Xml.XmlDocument/XmlDataDocument Load()
>   method is potentially unsafe, replace with the Load() overload that
>   takes an XmlReader instance

Any suggestions or any guidance? And when I replace with XmlReader do I need to use Using(try/catch/finally) to dispose XmlReader?

Comment: Well, your `XmlReader` implements `IDisposable`, so yes, you should dispose, or use a `using` block to automatically do so.

Comment: var configuration = new XmlDocument();
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(filePath))
                    {
                        configuration.Load(reader);
                    }
Is it correct? I did not find any reference for this code